# Convert escaped string back to original string

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a string that looks like this:

```
>>> st = 'aaaaa\x12bbbbb'
```

I can convert it to a raw string via:

```
>>> escaped_st = st.encode('string-escape')
'aaaaa\\x12bbbbb'
```

How can I convert the escaped string back to the original string? I was trying to do something like this:

```
escaped_st.replace('\\\\', '\\')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode the encoded string with the same encoding:

```
>>> st = 'aaaaa\x12bbbbb'
>>> escaped_st = st.encode('string-escape')
>>> escaped_st
'aaaaa\\x12bbbbb'
>>> escaped_st.decode('string-escape')
'aaaaa\x12bbbbb'
```